# Is "The motorist in the middle of the road lying beside his damaged vehicle." a sentence?

Tags: grammar

I'm preparing for an English exam. This sentence arrangement is confusing me. It says "The motorist in the middle of the road lying beside his damaged vehicle." is correct. But it's not like a sentence to me. Here are the choices:

__________ beside his damaged vehicle.

1. The motorist in the middle of the road lying
2. Lay in the middle of the road the motorist
3. In the middle of the road the motorist lay in the middle
4. In the road in the middle the motorist lay

I chose 3 but the answer is 1 without explanation. I've tried looking for grammar rules but feel hopeless. I'm thankful for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a sentence.  It is a noun phrase.

The main noun is "Motorist" It has a determiner "The" and two adjuncts (descriptive phrases) a proposition phrase and a participle phrase.

> [The motorist] [in the middle of the road] [lying beside his damaged vehicle.]

There is no finite verb, and no main clause. So it is not a sentence.

It is not clear if this is a mistake on the test or not.  It may be that they are looking for a correctly structured phrase (it is) and not always a sentence.

All the other alternatives are certainly incorrect syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much, James K. I think you're right that there might be a mistake. Maybe I find another book with more explanations.

Comment: Given the capitalization and ending period, it seems like this question is indeed asking for a full sentence, and in that case, I agree that the question was badly written and there is no correct answer.